# Use selectize with data-binding in vuejs component with vuex

Tags: vue.js, selectize.js, vuex

I made a component which is basically bootstrap modal. In the modal I want to use selectize (I also tried bootstrap select). The problem is that if the select has some static values it works, while if I fill it with dynamic data it fails with: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Here is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="newContactModalType">Type*</label>
    <select id="newContactModalType" name="type_id">
        <option v-for="type in clientTypes" value="{{ type.id }}">{{ type.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the component:

```
  export default {
    vuex: {
      getters: {
        clientTypes: state => state.clientTypes.list
      }
    },

    events: {
      'showNewContactModal': () => {
        $('#newContactModal').modal()
      }
    },

    ready() {
      $('#newContactModalType').selectize()
    }
  }
```

I'm using vuex to get the clientTypes list. As I realize this is where something's wrong, because it works if I define clientTypes in component's data property. I'm not sure where I should call `.selectize()` too. The best I could think of is the ready() method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a vue.js component: https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect

Comment: Nope, https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/issues/30 I got this issue

Comment: Try putting your .selectize() inside a jquery $(document).ready() inside the vue ready.

Comment: Putting your initialize statement inside $(document).ready works! But do NOT put that inside the Vue Ready(). that has worked for me. does also work with select2.JS and I guess Chosen should work too.